# Do I need to partition my SSD for a windows 10 dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, 19.10

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell Optiplex-7040. I have 2 x 1TB SSDs. The 1st is used for my Ubuntu, the 2nd one is empty and unmounted (partition type: NTFS/exFAT/HPFS). I would like to install Windows 10 (dual boot) on the 2nd SSD.

As I understand, the 2nd SSD is in the correct format to install Windows 10 (NTFS). Do I need to 'partition' the 2nd SSD using something like gparted, or if I am happy to use the entire 2nd SSD as a place to install Windows 10, is this uncessary? If not, is it simply a case of hitting `esc` during the boot sequence and booting from my USB which I have formatted to NTFS and added a Windows iso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the partition configuration on an SSD before a Windows installation is rarely necessary.

However, just to make sure, I would indeed use gparted to remove every partition. Once you launch the Windows installation, you will eventually get a partition manager screen where you will be able to configure your hard drive. You don't need to worry about swap or a boot partition. The installation will add them automatically for you.

And yes, you will need to access your installation media by hitting the appropriate key for your motherboard during the POST. For some its DEL, sometimes it's f2, f12.

Be aware, Windows might not like your current bootloader (probably grub) so it's highly probable that you will need to reconfigure or reinstall it.